# How to cat the first page of an epub file?

Tags: shell-script, file-format, pandoc, calibre, epub

```
epubcat book.epub 1 3
# outputs plain text of pages 1 through 3
```

I don’t know if epubs have the concept of “pages.” If not, perhaps we can say each 400 chars are a page?
A general solution that works for other ebook formats is better (mobi, azw3, etc).

My own thoughts are currently on first converting the book to text via ebook-convert or pandoc and then extracting the needed amount, but this seems awfully inefficient as I intend to only get a little of the beginning of the content.

You can download an example file that can be used for testing [here](http://82.102.11.148:8080//tmp/Time%20to%20Put%20Your%20Galleons%20Where%20Your%20Mouth%20Is%20-%20Tsume%20Yuki.epub).

Comment: You can read `.epub` books with this [.jar tool](https://github.com/bayang/termepub). However, I didn't find any way how to use it in shell script.

Comment: Can you link us to a file we can use for testing?

Comment: @terdon here: http://82.102.11.148:8080//tmp/Time%20to%20Put%20Your%20Galleons%20Where%20Your%20Mouth%20Is%20-%20Tsume%20Yuki.epub

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mutool`](https://mupdf.com/docs/mutool.html):

```bash
mutool draw -F text file.epub 1 2>/dev/null
```

The redirection `2>/dev/null` is optional.